# Images Pulled with JS Breaking Equal Height Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tumblr

It looks like my problems never end with this site. I'm using jQuery to pull posts tagged "_featured" into the sidebar on a Tumblr blog. I have it calling the title of the text post along with the image included in it. Unfortunately, no matter what I try, this breaks the equal height columns on any page where the content column isn't longer than the sidebars.

I've tried different methods of achieving equal columns (I'm currently using [The Equal Heights jQuery Plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) since I'm already using jQuery on the site. I've also tried the padding/negative margin trick and good ol' Faux Equal Columns using a background image. I figured it would be easy to solve it by using the jQuery plugin and wrapping the function call in a $(window).load(function(), but it's still hit or miss (mostly miss right now for some reason).

If anyone has any suggestions, please, save my computer from being thrown. The obvious solution that I'm thinking might work would be to have the JS calling the featured posts to  also include the image size, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

The JS calling the featured posts can be viewed [here](http://static.tumblr.com/txv6iau/CoIll738q/featured.js) and the site itself is at [escapebadmusic.com](http://escapebadmusic.com).

Thanks again, everyone. I think I say this just about every time I post a question, but the help here has saved me a lot of time and frustration. It's always appreciated.

Comment: It's also broken where the content column is longer then the sidebars.

Answer (score 0):

Try running EqualHeights after dom has finished changing.
(to be more specific - you should run EqualHeights after doc.ready, **and** after you add your image, or changed anything in the dom that affects heights)

Comment: Shouldn't `$(window).load(function()` accomplish that, though?

Comment: some jquery functions have callbacks to run after they have changed dom, putting something like equalheights there is best option.